# MATLAB deploytool simulink Undefined function 'load_system'

Tags: matlab, deployment, compilation, simulink

I am using a MATLAB m file code which loads a simulink file, runs it and evaluats it so many times inside a complicated parallel loop.

It runs perfect at MATLAB environment. When compiling the code via `deploytool` command, installing it and running it from command line, I would have a difficult time.

At the line where it is loading the model,

```
mymodel= ... ;
load_system(mymodel);
```

I get the following error

```
C:\Program Files\mymain\application>Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: model
> In path at 109
  In addpath at 86
  In run_main at 3
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: data
> In path at 109
  In addpath at 86
  In run_main at 4
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: graphics
> In path at 109
  In addpath at 86
  In run_main at 5
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 2 workers.
Initializing ...
Undefined function 'load_system' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in run_main (line 40)


MATLAB:UndefinedFunction
```

I don't care about warnings (as I don't care about most of other MATLAB warnings) however I get error about not recognizing function to open a simulink model ('load_system') :

```
Undefined function 'load_system' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

I did a search and I found the following questions:

[load_system using MCR](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/27476-executing-the-function-find_system-and-load_system-using-mcr)

[Deployment of Simulink Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516506/deployment-of-simulink-models)

The first link says

[image: question highlight]

I just got confused: is deployment tools about compiling to C++ or to .NET ?
Is is supposed to increase speed or becomming stand-alone is the only advantage?

The problem with both links is that they talk about strategy. But how to implement them? How can I compile a MATLAB code which uses `load_system` and `sim` command to load and simulate a model?

Can anybody bring step by step solution for a very simple example of a MATLAB code (m file) simulating a model and then compiling both of them?

Comment: You cannot compile load_system and sim commands. You need MATLAB to run them.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence of your documentation screen shot is the important one.  As mentioned by @Navan (in a comment), Simulink functionality is not compatible with MATLAB Compiler.  That is, any m-code that uses Simulink functinality (`load_system`, `sim`, etc) will not execute when using the MATLAB Compiler.

Assuming that you have access to Simulink Coder, and that your model doesn't contain functionality that prevents it from being converted to c-code, then your only option is to develop your application in two parts:

1. With your Simulink model:  Use Simulink Coder to create an executable from your model.  There are several examples of doing this in the doc, including [Using RSIM Target for Batch Simulations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/examples/using-rsim-target-for-batch-simulations.html).  There are various command line options for passing new parameter sets and inputs to the executable via a mat file.  The results of the simulation (i.e what would normally be written to the MATLAB Workspace) gets written to a mat file created by the executable.
2. Within you MATLAB code: replace all Simulink functionality with a call (typically using the `system` function, as shown in the linked example) to the executable created in step 1.  Prior to this call you'll need to create a mat file with all your parameters in it; and after the call you'll want to read results from the mat file created by the executable.

It's not a trivial process, but is do-able.