# Matlab Builder NE with find_system

Tags: c#, matlab, simulink, matlab-compiler

Is 'find_system' command supported for packaging into a .NET dll with Matlab Builder NE?

What I need to do is to connect a C# GUI with simulink and verify if a desired block is in the simulink model or not while the user is still working on the model (with matlab open)

I know that this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) provides a list of supported toolboxes and functions, but there is no explicit mention to 'find_system' command. 
Also, I would like to be sure that 'find_system' will work as intended, example:

- String[] result =  MatlabDll.wrapper.find_system('mymodel/myblock')

Answer (score 0):

The list of [Ineligible Programs](http://www.mathworks.com/products/ineligible_programs/) is linked at the end of the page that you reference.  Note that no Simulink functionality is supported, and hence `find_system` is not supported.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282103/matlab-deploytool-simulink-undefined-function-load-system/31294908#31294908) for the only way to achieve this.

However, your question is somewhat contradictory, in that it relates to using MATLAB Builder NE, but also says you want to do the model interrogation while MATLAB is open.  You should clarify which of those two you want to do.